# How to define which foreign key navigation property should use?

Tags: entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

I have two model classes

**Registration**

```
public class Registration
{
    // PK
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    
    // FK's
    public string AspNetUsersId { get; private set; }
    public int TimetableId { get; private set; }

    // EF Navigation properties
    public Timetable Timetable { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    // EF ctor
    private Registration()
    {
    }

    // public ctor
    public Registration(string aspNetUsersId, int timetableId)
    {
        AspNetUsersId = aspNetUsersId;
        TimetableId = timetableId;
    }
}
```

**ApplicationUser**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   // some not relevant columns
}
```

When I try to execute this code

```
var registrationExists = _context.Registrations
     .Where(x => x.AspNetUsersId == user.Id 
          && x.TimetableId == timetable.Id)
     .SingleOrDefault();
```

I got an error

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name
> 'ApplicationUserId'.

I think that is because EF is trying to find (by default convention) `Registration.ApplicationUserId` column in database because of `ApplicationUser` navigation property. But the property (and sql column) is named `AspNetUsersId` and not `ApplicationUserId`. How can I override this naming in model builder (dbContext) ?

I tried something like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>(b => 
{
    b.HasAlternateKey(x => x.AspNetUsersId);
    b.HasOne(n => n.ApplicationUser); 
});
```

but I did not figure, how to map it together.

Comment: [Relationships - Manual configuration - Foreign key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#foreign-key)

Comment: It would be good to read the whole Relationships topic - it explains terms, what they mean and how to configure different aspects. For instance, [Manual configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#manual-configuration) say *"To configure a relationship in the Fluent API, you start by identifying the navigation properties that make up the relationship. `HasOne` or `HasMany` identifies the navigation property on the entity type you are beginning the configuration on...*

Comment: *...You then chain a call to `WithOne` or `WithMany `to identify the inverse navigation. `HasOne/WithOne` are used for reference navigation properties and `HasMany/WithMany` are used for collection navigation properties."* Simply said, you need `HasXXX` followed by `WithXXX` in order to get other methods like `HasForeignKey` etc.

Comment: I tried to use `HasOne` method, but it does not have any additional methods to configure foreign key. I have to use `WithMany` but then I am configuring two-ways relationship instead of one-way. So I really don't know how to configure it. But now, it works with data annotation attribute `[ForeignKey("AspNetUsersId")]` above the `ApplicationUser` property. But I don't know how to set up the same with model builder ?

Comment: Ok, but `WithOne` or `WithMany` has parameter where I need to select navigation property from `ApplicationUser` class pointing back to the registration class. But I don't have any navigation field in `ApplicationUser` class. I can create it and it will work, but I don't need this two-way navigation relation. So my question is how to set relation from registration to `applicationUser` without navigation from `applicationUser` to registration. The `ForeignKey` attribute works, but I don't know how to make the same with FluentAPI (model builder).

Comment: It's right below in the previous link - [Single navigation property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1). If you don't have navigation property, use `WithXXX()` w/o passing selector.  In your case, `b.HasOne(n => n.ApplicationUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(...)`. Again, all this is explained with examples in the documentation, just need to read the whole topic. I see no value of posting answer with basically copy/paste from documentation just adjusted for your model.

Comment: @IvanStoev thank you very much, it works now without providing navigation property :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an annotation on the fields, e.g.

```
// PK
[Key]
public int Id { get; private set; }
    
// FK's
[ForeignKey(nameof(AspNetUsersId))]
public string AspNetUsersId { get; private set; }
[ForeignKey(nameof(TimetableId ))]
public int TimetableId { get; private set; }
```

Now, the property the [key] is the primary key and the properties with [ForeignKey()] are the FK's.

You can also use the modelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Registration>( 
  .HasAlternateKey(x => x.AspNetUsersId)
  .HasOne(n => n.ApplicationUser)
  .WithMany()
  .HasForeignKey(f => f.AspNetUsersId);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#single-navigation-property-1)

https://entityframeworkcore.com/model-relationships

Comment: see the powerful fluent API with all data annotations here: https://entityframeworkcore.com/model-data-annotations

Comment: Thank you, the foreign key annotation attribute did the trick
`[ForeignKey("AspNetUsersId")]
public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }`

but do you know, how to set up the same with Fluent API (model builder) ?

Comment: On the same site (https://entityframeworkcore.com/model-relationships) are also described, how to set a foreign key: e.g.: .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.BookId);

Comment: Can you please update/fix your answer with correct attribute or with model builder code (As @IvanStoev wrote to his comment) ? I would like to close this question and accept the answer.